# How to create the value I want by combining two pivot tables

Tags: pivot-table

I have combined two datas which are price 2013 and volume 2013 to create one pivot table. But how can I find revenue (Volume multiply price) by using pivot table? Please help. Thanks. My column field there included Price from data 1 and volume from data 2.

Comment: Can you show your schema ?

Answer (score 0):

Switch one of the fields to Σ Values (Volume would seem to be the more sensible) and add a Calculated Field (PivotTable Tools, Options > Tools - Formulas) say Named: Revenue and with Formula: Volume*Price.

However depending upon your version of Excel and your data, you may receive incorrect results (eg in the GT row for revenue).